# What is the difference between Pack- and Bat- on a LiPo Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, measurement, texas-instruments

I am trying to figure out how to use the TI [bq34z100](http://www.ti.com/product/bq34z100) to measure the charge in a 29.6v 8s1p 5.4Ah pack.  Out of this pack I have A charge connector with + and - and a discharge connector with + and -

There is already a PCM and charge module in the battery.

[image]

On the data sheet it shows a connection to Bat- and Pack-

What is the difference between these 2 connections?
How would I connect the bq34z100 to my Battery?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question as best as I can. According to TIs data sheet, the PACK positive pin senses input voltage, and wakes up the device when it is in shutdown mode. While BATT positive is the battery stack voltage sense input. Between BATT negative and PACK negative, should be the sense resistor.  Here is a link to your device's data sheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq34z100.pdf

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited my question to include the pcb drawing of my battery.  Could you advise me where I would need to connect to?